# How to check whether the http request is active at the moment?

Tags: angular, httpclient

I need your help. I'm trying to execute an http post request, and depending on whether it's happening now (active) or has already happened, I want to show a `progress-bar`. For this, I use the `Angular Material` library. With the code below, I try to do this, I don't get any errors, but unfortunately I only get the final result: `progress-bar` value: 100 and the message that I have everything loaded. And when I have a request (pending), my progress bar and message do not change. What is my problem? Why the progress bar and messages do not change? Thank you very much

HTML

```
<div>
  <p #message> {{ messageDownloadData }} </p>
<mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" value="0" *ngIf="isLoading === false && isLoaded === false"></mat-progress-bar>
<mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate" *ngIf="isLoading === true && isLoaded === false"></mat-progress-bar>
<mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" value="100" *ngIf="isLoading === false && isLoaded === true"></mat-progress-bar>
<button (click) = "downloadData()"> Save </button>
</div>
```

TypeScript

```
public isLoading: boolean = false;
public isLoaded: boolean = false;
public messageDownloadData: string;

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.messageDownloadData = 'Click to download connections';
}

public downloadData() {
   this.service.downloadData(body).subscribe(res => {
     this.isLoading = true;
     if (this.isLoading === true || !res) {
//doesn`t work
        this.renderer.addClass(this.messageInfoParagraph.nativeElement, 'inProgress_pulsating_message');
        this.messageDownloadData = `Operation in progress`;
     }
     if (res) {
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.isLoaded = true;
        this.renderer.removeClass(this.messageInfoParagraph.nativeElement, 'inProgress_pulsating_message');
        this.messageDownloadData = 'Connections has been downloaded';
     }
   })
}
```

Service

```
public downloadData(body: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(url, body);
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code of your service?

Answer (score 0):

You set `isLoading` within the subscription block. Move it to the function body, so it is set before the call.

```
public downloadData() {
   this.isLoading = true; // <-- MOVE ME TO HERE
   this.service.downloadData(body).subscribe(res => {
     // MOVE ME FROM HERE
     if (this.isLoading === true || !res) {
//doesn`t work
        this.renderer.addClass(this.messageInfoParagraph.nativeElement, 'inProgress_pulsating_message');
        this.messageDownloadData = `Operation in progress`;
     }
     if (res) {
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.isLoaded = true;
        this.renderer.removeClass(this.messageInfoParagraph.nativeElement, 'inProgress_pulsating_message');
        this.messageDownloadData = 'Connections has been downloaded';
     }
   })
}
```